# Theme system having to tell which view to return at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razorengine

I have the following extension which tells my theme system how to find the view. On each controller I have to do this.

```
private IConfiguration _config;
public HomeController(IConfiguration config) 
{ 
  _config = config; // would rather not have to do this each time but some how have the 
   system smart enough to no which view layout to return
}

public static string GetViewPath(string controller,string action, string themeName = "Default")
{           
        ViewResult result = new ViewResult();
        result.ViewName = $"/Themes/{themeName}/{controller}/{action}" + ".cshtml";           
        var viewResult = $"/Themes/{themeName}/{controller}/{action}" + ".cshtml";
        return viewResult;
}
```

On the home controller I have this. Which tells the system to return the front end view.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
 return View(ThemeViewExtensions.GetViewPath(@"Home","Index",_config.GetValue("Theme"));
}
```

I dont want to have to explain in my documentation the user needs to do this for every theme? Bound to be an easier way?

I also have a theme expander for locations my question is is their a way I can make the above neater so I do not need to return the above in the view controllers each time.

```
public class ThemeableViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{         
   public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext
    context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
{    
    context.Values.TryGetValue(Constants.ThemeConfigKey, out string theme);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(theme) && !string.Equals(theme, "Generic", 
     System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var moduleViewLocations = new string[]
        {
            $"/Themes/{theme}/Areas/{{2}}/Views/{{1}}/{{0}}.cshtml",
            $"/Themes/{theme}/Areas/{{2}}/Views/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml",
            $"/Views/Admin/{{1}}/{{0}}.cshtml",

            $"/Themes/{theme}/Views/{{1}}/{{0}}.cshtml",
            $"/Themes/{theme}/Views/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml"
        };

        viewLocations = moduleViewLocations.Concat(viewLocations);
    }

    return viewLocations;
}


public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
{
    var controllerName = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;
    if (controllerName == null) // in case of render view to string
    {
        return;
    }
       
    var config = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    context.Values[Constants.ThemeConfigKey] = config["Theme"];

 }
}
```

I guess what I need to no is how does one access the configuration from the getviewpath method so it can be seamless for the user and is their a way i can achieve this so they dont have to even type this extension name ("Home","Index")?

Is their a way i can just stick to the .net standard and have
return view(); under the hood it would render the front end layout to the user.

Im using a efcore provider to save my settings to Theme so Theme=FrontEnd

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else I found this answer you need to override the view interal method on your base class of any controller you want to override.

https://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/17/mobile-views-in-asp-net-mvc3/
Credit to the original other code still seems valid for 2021 .net 5

```
protected new internal ViewResult View()
{
    if (!IsMobile()) return base.View();
 
    var viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    CheckForMobileEquivalentView(ref viewName, ControllerContext);
 
    return base.View(viewName, (object)null);
}
 
protected new internal ViewResult View(object model)
{
    if (!IsMobile()) return base.View(model);
 
    var viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    CheckForMobileEquivalentView(ref viewName, ControllerContext);
 
    return base.View(viewName, model);
}
 
protected new internal ViewResult View(string viewName)
{
    if (!IsMobile()) return base.View(viewName);
 
    CheckForMobileEquivalentView(ref viewName, ControllerContext);
    return base.View(viewName);
}
 
protected new internal ViewResult View(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (!IsMobile()) return base.View(viewName, model);
 
    CheckForMobileEquivalentView(ref viewName, ControllerContext);
    return base.View(viewName, model);
}
 
// Need this to prevent View(string, object) stealing calls to View(string, string)
protected new internal ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName)
{
    return base.View(viewName, masterName);
}
```

**Edit 2**

What I basically did to be more precise was this. Now I will eventually store the theme name somewhere just doing this as a proof of concept. Obv would not want to hit out every time to get the theme name.

```
protected new internal ViewResult View()
{
   base.View();
   var rd = this.RouteData;
   string currentController = rd.Values["controller"].ToString();
   string currentAction = rd.Values["action"].ToString();
   string themeName = _config["Theme"];
   
   var viewName = ThemeViewExtensions.GetViewPath(currentController, currentAction,themeName);

    return base.View(viewName, (object)null);
}
```

One question is passing null in base.view a good idea would it not destory any data user has sent